# Debug log for BI Publisher 11g

Tags: bi-publisher

I am running BI Publisher on Weblogic.  I am having issues, probably related to the SQL queries being issued to generate reports.  Does anyone know how to turn on debugging so that I can see the SQL that the system is attempting to execute?

Comment: I think you will have to log on to the BI App server and check the instance logs there. I think there is no way to turn on debugging in BI Publisher (atleast in Version 10g).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it.  Find the location of JAVA_HOME by opening a command prompt and typing:

```
>set JAVA
```

You should see something like  this:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\OracleBI\oc4j_bi
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16
set J2EE_HOME=%ORACLE_HOME%\j2ee\home
```

Once you find the JDK home location, go to the folder:

```
<JDK_Home>\jre\lib
```

Create a text file called: xdodebug.cfg
Add the following 2 lines to the file:

```
LogLevel=STATEMENT
LogDir=<BI_Debug_Log_Directory>
```

For Example:

```
LogLevel=STATEMENT
LogDir=D:\apps\BI_Debug
```

Save the file and restart WebLogic.

There should now be many files created when you run BI Publisher such as xdo.log, which will 
 show you just what the heck BIP is doing under  the hood.